# what should I do to make the not in more efficient

Tags: postgresql

I have two table article and article_content in PostgreSQL, the article_id in table article_content was the article table id. Now the sql look like this:

```
select * 
from article_content ac 
where article_id not in(
   select id from article a 
)
limit 10
```

find the record in article_content that not exists in article. this is the query plain:

```
Limit  (cost=1000.00..44996.68 rows=1 width=415)
  ->  Gather  (cost=1000.00..38955542254.16 rows=885420 width=415)
        Workers Planned: 2
        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on article_content ac  (cost=0.00..38955452712.16 rows=368925 width=415)
              Filter: (NOT (SubPlan 1))
              SubPlan 1
                ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..101153.51 rows=1775167 width=8)
                      ->  Seq Scan on article a  (cost=0.00..85342.67 rows=1775167 width=8)
```

now the table article and article_content have so many rows. seems this sql could not complete forever. what should I do to do remove the article content rows that did not exists in artcle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically NOT EXISTS is more efficient:

```
select ac.* 
from article_content ac 
where not exists (select *
                  from article a 
                  where a.id = ac.article_id)
limit 10;
```

An index on `article_content (article_id)` will improve the performance. I assume there is already an index on `article (id)`